# Hide default text in a field - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, hide, field

I want that when I click on any field, the default text will be hidden and when I enter text into it and I click again the same field the text will not be hide it.

I tried this code but it doesn't work

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onfocus = function() {
        if(typeof value1 != undefined) {
             this.value = value1;

        }else {
            value = this.value;
            this.value = '';
            this.style.color = "#000";
        }
    }

    inputs[i].onblur = function() {
            if(this.value == '' || this.value == value) {
                this.value = value;
                this.style.color = "#707070";
            }else {
                value1 = this.value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the placeholder attribute?

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name">
```

If you do not want HTML 5, you will have to simulate of course. You will have to add a class to flag the "state" of the input field and test on that.

```
<input id="fname" type="text" value="enter first name" />
<input id="lname" type="text" value="enter last name" />

$("input[type='text']").each(function () {
    $(this).focus(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("has-input")) {
            $(this).val($(this).val());
        } else {
            $(this).val("");
        }
    })

    $(this).blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() !== '') {
            $(this).addClass('has-input');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('has-input');
        }
        if (!$(this).hasClass('has-input')) {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('value'));
        }
    })

});
```

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/sq7V3/3/

Comment: i dont want to use HTML5 for this time

Comment: Why are you stressing the DOM/Browser with every keyup?

Comment: @Lilith - notice the change made. You are correct and this is more graceful.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var box=document.getElementById("text");
function clearTextbox(){ if(box.value==="Default")box.value=""; }
function checkContent(){ if(box.value==="") box.value="Default" }
box.addEventListener("focus", clearTextbox);
box.addEventListener("blur", checkContent);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cr8dH/1/

More generic version: http://jsfiddle.net/cr8dH/5/

Comment: But i want when i click again in the same field, the text entered will not be hiding

Comment: But i have several text fields with several default text, i think your code don't help me much

Comment: A data object is not necessary and overhead administration if the default text value is enclosed in the "value-attribute" of the input element.

Comment: But it is needed for resetting it to the default.